# Windows 8 won't boot, BCD error

Tags: windows-8, boot, mbr, bcd

My Windows 8 laptop has a boot problem. When Windows tries to boot, I get this error message:

```
Boot configuration data is missing  
File: \BCD  
Error code: 0xc0000034
```

So as suggested I booted to the console and tried:

```
bootrec /fixmbr
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /scanos
bootrec /rebuildbcd
```

After the last command I got:

```
Total identified win installations:1
[1] C:\Windows 
Add installation to boot list?
```

I typed `y` so I want to add installation, but got a reply:

```
The requested system device cannot be found.
```

As a solution I found a diskpart - select and activate OS partition, so I selected OS partition and typed:

```
active
```

I got a reply that:

```
The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. 
The active command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.
```

How to fix this problem, to get Windows 8 boot properly? My laptop is a repair of a previously working PC.

Comment: Try using: BCDboot c:/windows /s c: /l en-us

Comment: `Boot files successfully created` but Windows won't boot anyway, still get same error.

Comment: Did you try the initial sequence of commands you tried previously afterwards?

Comment: Yes, with same result. `bootrec /rebuildbcd` returns "The requested system device cannot be found. " and after rester Windows won't boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to refresh computer (after no solution found), I get error saying something like:

`PC can't be refreshed, because your disk is locked.`

So I tied to unlock HDD as [this tutorial say](http://vetalk.com/windows-8-hard-drive-lock-solution/) but with Windows 8 installation disc.

I choose to install, after few seconds error:

`Bad serial number ...`

I submitted this window by clicking OK button. After submitting I choose

`Turn off computer`

in Windows installation menu. After turning off and powering up everything was working great, no other steps required

Comment: link is dead. Can you provide us with what you did to unlock the HDD? Thanks.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150222012543/http://vetalk.com/windows-8-hard-drive-lock-solution

Answer (score 5):

This page helped me restore the BCD on my Intel RSTe Raid SSD Configuration for Windows 7, on UEFI ASRock X79 Extreme 9 after upgrading the Bios.

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk 0 #Select the desired disk
create partition efi size=100
list partition #Make sure that the 100mb partition is selected
format quick fs=fat32 label="System"
assign letter=B
create partition msr size=128
list partition #Check for errors
list vol
select vol 3 #Use the number corresponding to your windows installation
assign letter=C
exit
```

Now copy the EFI files by typing:

```
mkdir B:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot
xcopy /s C:\Windows\Boot\EFI\*.* B:\EFI\Microsoft\Boot
```

Now we will set the boot configuration data by typing:

```
b:
cd EFI\Microsoft\Boot
bcdedit /createstore BCD
bcdedit /store BCD  /create {bootmgr} /d “Windows Boot Manager”
bcdedit /store BCD /create /d “Windows 7” /application osloader
#This will return a GUID, referred to later as {guid}
bcdedit /store BCD /set {bootmgr} default {guid}
bcdedit /store BCD /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
bcdedit /store BCD /set {bootmgr} displayorder {default}
#Now it's not {bootmgr} anymore but {default}!
bcdedit /store BCD /set {default} device partition=c:
bcdedit /store BCD /set {default} osdevice partition=c:
bcdedit /store BCD /set {default} path \Windows\System32\winload.efi
bcdedit /store BCD /set {default} systemroot \Windows
exit
```

Credit to: http://www.hasper.info/repair-a-destroyed-windows-7-uefi-boot-sector/

Comment: your method did showed `Windows Boot manager` for me, but it was not able to boot into Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me for the second time earlier today and I was getting the `hardware can't be found` error using just `bootrec` so I shall talk you through the steps I used.

Entering the following commands into the recovery terminal on the installation media disk. The first set fix the Master Boot Record (MBR) and the Bootsectors.

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr
bootsect.exe /nt60 all /force
```

I then attempted to rebuild the Boot Config Data (BCD)

```
bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

This solved it for me, however if you need further steps, then the information I have used (and more) can be found on [this](https://neosmart.net/wiki/recovering-windows-bootloader/#Booting_from_the_Windows_Installation_DVD) website.

Comment: Hello!  While this link may provide a solution, link-only answers are a no-no.  Please include pertinent information directly in your answers and cite the site as a source.

Comment: @techie007 Hi. I'm sorry and I wasn't aware of this. Hopefully the edit I've made is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party but if everything else fails you can run :

```
Bcdboot c:\windows /s c: /f UeFI /v
```

Use `/f bios /v` if it's a MBR disk

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.Insert your Installation Disk

2.Go to repair Windows

3.Command Prompt

4.type in this:

"BootRec.exe /rebuildbcd" and press enter, then type in
"BootRec.exe /fixmbr" and press enter, and finally type in
"BootRec.exe /fixboot" and press  enter.
Now restart the PC and try it.

Comment: /rebuildbcd returned me 'The requested system device cannot be found.' But I wrote solution above... Thanks for answer anyway.