# Windows 8 boot error: Boot Configuration Data is missing

Tags: windows-8, boot, bios, bcd

When I try to boot to Windows 8 it gives me this message.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \BCD

  Status: 0xc00000e9

  Info: Boot Configuration Data is missing
```

I have tried to do as it was mentioned on this answer, but then I get the same output as the question. It seems that the disk was locked or something. [Windows 8 won't boot, BCD error](https://superuser.com/questions/675378/windows-8-wont-boot-bcd-error)

```
The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk. 
The active command can only be used on fixed MBR disks.
```

- I tried this method on an another computer using the same HD, Since My Acer V5 is locked. The Bios Password has been forgotten. Also if anyone knows, What is that BIOS PASSWORD HINT number on acer Laptops.?

Can Anyone please tell me how to Fix this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to remove a hard disk from one computer and put it into another and expect it to boot properly is very limited and may not work at all as in your case.

The error you are receiving regarding

```
The selected disk is not a fixed MBR disk.
```

Maybe an accurate error, in that the disk you removed might not be an MBR disk at all, but rather a GPT disk.

Attaching it to another working computer by means of a USB docking station or cables intended for such purpose and examining the properties of the disk, might reveal more information as to the actual disk configuration and whether or not it is functional at all.
As far as your BIOS Password lock is concerned you may have to actually contact Acer to see if they have a solution.
Short of disconnecting it from all power sources including the motherboard CMOS battery (or possibly a BIOS jumper somewhere on the motherboard), I don't think that there is anything an end user can do to overcome that.